# Fill mesh not working?

Tags: modeling

So I make a cylinder, deleted a couple of vertices, and warped into this shape.

[image]

For some reason though when I try to go and fill in the missing faces, the fill tool doesn't for me. I tried the basic fill and grid fill but none of them fill in the faces.

Comment: Using fill will create a single ngon face with a lot of vertices. You should avoid that. Use **grid fill**, so that you can keep the topology as quads.

Comment: If I understand this correctly you need to Apply the Warp modifier before you can create the faces in Edit Mode with the F key.

Comment: I was using ctrl+f to try and fill in the spots. Didn't know you could just hit the f key. Also even then, grid fill doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the "f" hotkey to fill in any edges or vertexes you have selected, you could try that and see if it works.

Comment: If the "f" hotkey is producing triangles - You must enable the **F2 Addon** to fill with quads (squares.) To use "New edge/face from vertex" without making triangles (or to *choose* between tris versus quads) enabling the F2 Addon for Blender fills with quads by default, and disabling the F2 addon returns blender to filling with tris.

Comment: F2 Addon helped! Thank you!